# mplot3d python incompatible dimensions error

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, mplot3d

I am trying to plot a 2D array in 3D with python mplot3d however I am getting an error about incompatible dimensions on axis 1
I have looked at other questions where answers have suggested using meshgrid but I am already using that and still getting an error, my X and Y ranges also multiply to the number of Z values.
here is my code:

```
def view_3d(map3d):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    X = []
    Y = []
    Z = []
    for wid in range(len(map3d)):
        X.append(wid)
        for hi in range(len(map3d[wid])):
            if wid is 0:
                Y.append(hi)
            Z.append(map3d[wid][hi])
    print(len(X), len(Y), len(Z))
    X = np.array(X)
    Y = np.array(Y)

    X2, Y2 = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
    Z = np.array(Z)
    print(len(X2),len(Y2),len(Z))
    print(len(X2[0]), len(Y2[0]))
    surf = ax.plot_surface(X2, Y2, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
            linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

    ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
    ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

    fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

    plt.show()
```

The passed 2d array (map3d) have lengths of 566-by-566

The print statements were just to confirm the lengths of the arrays

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__init__.py", line 199, in <module>
    view_3d(map_results)
  File "__init__.py", line 163, in view_3d
    linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py", line 1564, in plot_surface
    X, Y, Z = np.broadcast_arrays(X, Y, Z)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py", line 101, in broadcast_arrays
    "incompatible dimensions on axis %r." % (axis,))
ValueError: shape mismatch: two or more arrays have incompatible dimensions on axis 1.
```

A google drive link to the code and images required to run the code and view the error is below:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2ssDQewnhReWGJZYXZRSXNxRFU&usp=sharing

All help is appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Please provide the data to reproduce the error. At least you could provide the error message. Otherwise it will be very hard to help you.

Comment: I have added a link to the code and the error which occured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Z` array must have the same shape as `X2,Y2` in order `plot_surface` to work.
So I changed the line

```
Z = np.array(Z)
```

to

```
Z = np.array(Z).reshape(Y.size,X.size)
```

and It worked!